# How can I add class to parent navigation item without adding it to children navigation items in craft?

Tags: twig, craftcms

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('interests').all() %}
{% nav page in pages %}
<div class="nav__column">
    <li class="nav__parent">
        {{ page.getLink() }}
            {% ifchildren %}
                  <ul>
                        {% children %}
                  </ul>
             {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
</div>
{% endnav %}
```

When using this every nav item has the class of nav parent
Can I determine what classes are on the nav item depending on whether it is a child or parent nav item?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap that class in the ifchildren conditional, e.g:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages') %}

<ul id="nav">
{% nav entry in entries %}
    <li{% ifchildren %} class="nav__parent{% endifchildren %}">
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
</ul>
```

As an aside, your example code is invalid markup; `<li>` elements can only appear within a valid list type, e.g. `<ul>` or `<ol>`.